# When I try to enable migrations in code first mvc then I got this error but don't understand what the causes behind this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Error:

> The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was
>   generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First
>   development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not
>   remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use
>   Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity
>   Framework connection string is included in the app.config or
>   web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own
>   DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not
>   some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the
>   base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more
>   about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity
>   Framework documentation here:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LibraryDBContext" connectionString="data source=.; database=LibraryDB; integrated security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Context:

```
  public class LibraryDBContext:DbContext
    {
        public LibraryDBContext()
            : base("LibraryDBContext")
        {

        }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Desk> Desks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Faculty> Faculties { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<LibraryBuildingLevel> LibraryBuildingLevels { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Librarian> Librarians { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Publication> Publications { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Shelf> Shelves { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<UserType> UserTypes { get; set; }

}
```

}

Comment: Please add the code for your DbContext. Seems like that's where the error is coming from.

Comment: It is saying that Context used by your code is not created by Code First. I think it is mix of code first and database/model first. Choose one.

Comment: I already added it but i got this problem

Comment: Find and remove any EDMX in your project(s).